# I want to install rrdiff gem but its giving me error that lrsync is not there, how to install and configure lrsync for mac apple m1 chip?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, gnu-make

I want to install rrdiff gem but its giving me error that lrsync is not there, how to install and configure lrsync for mac apple m1 chip so the gem install for rrdiff works properly?

Here is the lrsync:

[lrsync github link](https://github.com/xaionaro/lrsync)

Here are mkmf.log and gem_make.out files:

mkmf.log:

```
have_library: checking for -lrsync... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/-darwin20 -I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.7   "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/-darwin20 -I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.  -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib     -lruby.2.7 -lrsync   "
ld: library not found for -lrsync
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: 
15: int t(void) { ; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

gem_make.out:

```
current directory: /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bundler/gems/rrdiff-6742766bf0e0/ext/rrdiff
/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20210727-47852-a9wtwt.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lrsync... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-rsync-dir
    --without-rsync-dir
    --with-rsync-include
    --without-rsync-include=${rsync-dir}/include
    --with-rsync-lib
    --without-rsync-lib=${rsync-dir}/lib
    --with-rsynclib
    --without-rsynclib
extconf.rb:3:in `<main>': unhandled exception

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/aashishgangwani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bundler/gems/extensions/-darwin-20/2.7.0/rrdiff-6742766bf0e0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

[rrdif mkmf.log file](https://gist.github.com/aashishg/c213311a64ffd4462a92b1049e4176ac)

[rrdiff gem_make.out file](https://gist.github.com/aashishg/aaeb6ccd7bf435ea4484a567036f5dca)

I have tried to clone the repository of lrsync and do "make" into the folder but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Please add logs directly into your question rather than linking to external sites.

Comment: And you likely want [librsync](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/librsync) rather than your [lrsync](https://github.com/clsync/lrsync).

Comment: @HolgerJust Edited the question to include both the logs directly and linked it to external site. How do I install librync please? and will it solve my problem?

Comment: @HolgerJust I just came to know that librsync is already installed and up to date 
`Warning: librsync 2.3.2 is already installed and up-to-date.`